# How to find ip in range in very large struct

Tags: go

I have a struct like below, with about 100k entires.

I would like to loop over it and check if a ip address is in range.

My current code:

```
type Users struct {
    Id        string
    Descr     string
    IpStart   string
    IpEnd     string
}
var users []*Users



func LookUpIP(IpAddress string) (string, string) {
    iptocheck := net.ParseIP(IpAddress)
    for _, elem := range users {
        if bytes.Compare(iptocheck, elem.IpStart) >= 0 && bytes.Compare(iptocheck, elem.IpEnd) <= 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%v is between %v and %v\n", IpAddress, elem.IpStart, elem.IpEnd)
            return elem.Id, elem.Descr 
        }
    }
    return "0", "null"
}
```

The above works fine with about 40k entires but over that it gets slow. Is there any faster way to find out if a ip address is in range inside my struct?

Update: Now only parsing IP once and storing it as number in struct

Comment: Just an initial thought would be to store the user information in a map, with the ip address as the key.  Then you would not have to loop through the ip addresses when searching.

Comment: Can I do that since i want to find out if ip: 123.123.123.123 is in range of 123.123.123.1 and 123.123.123.250?

Comment: Will an IP ever fall into multiple ranges?  Meaning, would `123.123.123.123` ever be applicable to the ranges of 2+ users like ranges of `123.123.123.1 -> 123.123.123.250` and `123.123.123.128 -> 123.123.124.1`?

Answer (score 2):

There are two simple steps I see.

1. Do the parsing once and store the IP address as a single number.
2. Order the ranges by start of the range and use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

As a completion of [@Grzegorz Żur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450989/grzegorz-%C5%BBur) suggestion to use binary search for reducing the search time, here is a binary search implementation in go.

But first what is binary search? A binary search divides a range of values into halves, and continues to narrow down the field of search until the unknown value is found. It is the classic example of a "divide and conquer" algorithm.

The algorithm returns the index of some element that equals the given value (if there are multiple such elements, it returns some arbitrary one). It is also possible, when the element is not found, to return the "insertion point" for it (the index that the value would have if it were inserted into the array).

**The recursive method**

```
func binarySearch(a []float64, value float64, low int, high int) int {
    if high < low {
        return -1
    }
    mid := (low + high) / 2 // calculate the mean of two values
    if a[mid] > value {
        return binarySearch(a, value, low, mid-1)
    } else if a[mid] < value {
        return binarySearch(a, value, mid+1, high)
    }
    return mid
}
```

**The iterative method**

```
func binarySearch(a []float64, value float64) int {
    low := 0
    high := len(a) - 1
    for low <= high {
        mid := (low + high) / 2
        if a[mid] > value {
            high = mid - 1
        } else if a[mid] < value {
            low = mid + 1
        } else {
            return mid
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

But if you take a look into the [sort package](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Search) you can observe that there is an already implemented sorting algorithm based on binary search. So probably this would be the best option.